# attach a policy to an EKS cluster node group role

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks

I'd like to attach a policy created via the aws_iam_policy to a node group NodeInstanceRole, so far the only thing I've come across which would allow me to do this (if I understand this correctly) is the following code:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "additional" {
  for_each = {
    for node_group, group_details in module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups : node_group => group_details
    # We have to add if condition as the module output contains all node names,
    # even if they are not created.
    if group_details.iam_role_name != ""
  }

  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.s3_write_policy.arn
  role       = each.value.iam_role_name
}
```

This is from https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/2053, is this the way to go ?, or is there a better way for me to add my policy to my EKS cluster's node group role ?

I know how to attach a policy to a role, that is not the issue here, my issue is with getting to the name of the role.

Comment: I don't understand the need for the for_each without context, but `aws_iam_role_policy_attachment` is the standard way to attach a policy to a role.

Comment: Per my update to the question, I know how to attach a policy to a role, it’s getting the name of the role that is the issue, it has something like NodeGroupRole in the name, but it also has suffixes and prefixes depending on the name of the cluster

Comment: What you have looks fine ok me. Does it work? I would note that you should reconsider any strategy that expands the IAM capabilities of the node as the node itself should do very little.

Comment: What you need to understand is that each node group gets assigned a role. To apply the same update across all these roles, it is iterating the role arns. Agree with @jordanm the snippet looks normal the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I eventually managed to resolve this issue, I created two modules
In the eks_cluster and iam_policy, in one of the .tf files for the eks_cluster module I output the iam_role_name for the eks_managed_node_group as follows, note that I only have one of these:

```
output "nodegroup_iam_role" {
  value = module.eks.eks_managed_node_groups["one"].iam_role_name
}
```

I then pass this into the iam_policy module and assign a policy ARN to this inside of a aws_iam_role_policy_attachment resource.